# Coding Problem - Do I Use Pivot, XML, or Something Else

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, xml, pivot

I'm having a brain-not-working moment and could really use some help. This is SQL Server 2014 Standard ed.

I have 3 Tables - for simplicity, we'll call them "name", "address", and "international". Sample data below:

```
Name
-----
Id   Sequence   Name
---  --------   ------
101  1          Pluto
102  1          Mickey
102  2          Donald
102  3          C/O Goofy
103  1          Minnie
103  2          Sophie

Address
--------
Id      Address
-----   -------------
101     123 Somewhere
102     456 Over There St
103     987 Here Ln

International
-------------
Id      Address
----    ---------
101     Alberta
102     Germany
103     Poland
```

I need to put all this in a pipe-delimited format to later be exported to a file. It needs to look like this:
(I've lined them up in columns to make it easier to read)

```
101 | Pluto  | 123 Somewhere | Alberta      |               |
102 | Mickey | Donald        | C/O Goofy    |456 Overthere  |Germany
103 | Minnie | Sophie        | 987 Here     |Poland         |
```

Here is the code I've been using. The main problem with it are the duplicate values.

```
    CREATE TABLE name
    (
        id INT NULL
        ,seq INT NULL
        ,name VARCHAR(33) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO dbo.name
            ( id, seq, name )
    VALUES  ( 101, 1, 'Pluto' )
           ,( 102, 1, 'Mickey' )
           ,( 102, 2, 'Donald' )
           ,( 102, 3, 'c/o Goofy' )
           ,( 103, 1, 'Minnie' )
           ,( 103, 2, 'Sophie' )

    CREATE TABLE addr
    (
        id INT NULL
        ,addr VARCHAR(33) null
    )


    INSERT INTO dbo.addr
            ( id, addr )
    VALUES   ( 101, '123 Somewhere')
            ,( 102, '456 Over There St')
            ,( 103, '987 Here Ln')

    CREATE TABLE intl
    (
         id INT NULL
        ,intlAddr VARCHAR(33) null
    )

    INSERT INTO dbo.intl
            ( id, intlAddr )
    VALUES   ( 101, 'Alberta')
            ,( 102, 'Germany')
            ,( 103, 'Poland')



    DECLARE @results TABLE
    (
     namecount CHAR(3)
    ,id INT
    ,seq INT
    ,name CHAR(40)
    ,addr CHAR(40)
    ,intlAddr CHAR(60)
    ,namepivot CHAR(10)
    ,addrpivot CHAR(10)
    ,intlPivot CHAR(20)

    )

    INSERT INTO @results (namecount, id, seq,name,addr, intlAddr, namepivot, addrpivot, intlPivot)
    SELECT    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name.id ORDER BY name.seq) AS CHAR(3)) AS nameCount ,
                                name.id,
                                name.seq ,
                                CAST(ISNULL(name.name, '') AS CHAR(40)) AS name ,
                                CAST(ISNULL(addr.addr, '') AS CHAR(40)) AS addr ,
                                CAST(ISNULL(intl.intlAddr, '') AS CHAR(60)) AS intlAddr ,
                                'name'
                                + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name.id ORDER BY name.id, name.seq) AS CHAR(10)) AS namePivot ,
                                'addr'
                                + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY addr.id ORDER BY addr.id ) AS CHAR(10)) AS addrpivot ,
                                'intlAddr'
                                + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY intl.id ORDER BY intl.id ) AS CHAR(20)) AS intlPivot
    FROM       name
    INNER JOIN dbo.addr ON name.id = addr.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.intl ON name.id = intl.id

    SELECT * FROM @results


    SELECT  nameCount ,
            id,
            seq,        
            namelist,
            addrlist,
            intlList
        FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ( SELECT 1) ) rownum ,
                            1 nameCount ,
                            pd.id,
                            pd.seq ,                        
                            STUFF((SELECT   '|' + RTRIM(res.name) 
                                    FROM     @results res
                                    WHERE    pd.id = res.id 
                            FOR   XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS namelist,

                            STUFF((SELECT   '|' + RTRIM(res.addr)                                       
                                    FROM     @results res
                                    WHERE    pd.id = res.id
                            FOR   XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS addrlist,

                            STUFF((SELECT   '|' + RTRIM(res.intlAddr)
                                    FROM     @results res
                                    WHERE    pd.id = res.id
                            FOR   XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS intlList
                    FROM  @results pd
                ) nest1
        WHERE   nest1.rownum = 1;
```

The results end up looking like this:

```
        nameCount   id  seq namelist                    addrlist                                                intlList
        1           101 1   Pluto                       123 Somewhere                                           Alberta
        1           102 1   Mickey|Donald|c/o Goofy     456 Over There St|456 Over There St|456 Over There St   Germany|Germany|Germany
        1           103 1   Minnie|Sophie               987 Here Ln|987 Here Ln                                 Poland|Poland
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

I need to account for all 5 "buckets" somehow. Like this with the pipes at the end:

```
Pluto|123 Somewhere|Alberta|||
Mickey|Donald|c/o Goofy|456 Over There St|Germany|
Minnie|Sophie|987 Here Ln|Poland||
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is almost certainly a better way to do this but this one works and will probably get you started on a better solution.

```
SELECT nameid.id, 
        STUFF((SELECT   '|' + RTRIM(res.name) 
                FROM     name res
                WHERE    nameid.id = res.id 
        FOR   XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
        + '|' + 
        STUFF((SELECT   '|' + RTRIM(res.addr)                                       
                FROM     addr res
                WHERE    nameid.id = res.id
        FOR   XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
        + '|' + 
        STUFF((SELECT   '|' + RTRIM(res.intlAddr)
                FROM     intl res
                WHERE    nameid.id = res.id
        FOR   XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') 

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM name) AS nameid
ORDER BY nameid.id
```

---

And again there is probably a better way to do this but:

```
WITH myCTE AS (
        SELECT id, 1 as ord,  '|' + RTRIM(res.name) AS Col
        FROM     name res
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 2 as ord,  '|' + RTRIM(res.addr)                            
        FROM     addr res
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 3 as ord,  '|' + RTRIM(res.intlAddr)
        FROM     intl res
        ),
NameId AS (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM name)
SELECT nameid.id, 
        STUFF((
        SELECT TOP (6) Col FROM 
        (
            SELECT ord, Col FROM myCTE
            WHERE myCTE.id = nameid.id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP (6) 4 as ord, '|' FROM sys.columns
        ) a
        ORDER BY ord
        FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
FROM NameId
ORDER BY NameId.id
```

Answer (score 2):

That works! Thank you! :-)

I ended up making a small adjustment/change but it works! Thank you! I need to keep the names in the right order so I adjusted the order numbers. I need to retrieve only the first 3 name sequences even if there are more.

```
    ;WITH myCTE AS (
            SELECT id, seq as ord,  '|' + RTRIM(res.name) AS Col
            FROM     name res
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, 4 as ord,  '|' + RTRIM(res.addr)                            
            FROM     addr res
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, 5 as ord,  '|' + RTRIM(res.intlAddr)
            FROM     intl res
            ),
    NameId AS (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM name)

    SELECT nameid.id, 
            STUFF((
            SELECT TOP (6) Col FROM 
            (
                SELECT ord, Col FROM myCTE
                WHERE myCTE.id = nameid.id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT TOP (6) 6 as ord, '|' FROM sys.columns
            ) a
            ORDER BY ord
            FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
    FROM NameId
    ORDER BY NameId.id
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select distinct b.id,(select  name+'' from name a where a.id=b.id for xml path ('')  )
from name b, addr addr, intl intl
where  addr.id=b.id
and intl.id=b.id
```

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! I suggest to explain, what your query is doing and how.